# Ruby hash keys to array conditional on hash value

Tags: ruby, hash

I would like to extract hash key values to an array when a condition is met. For example, with hash h I want to extract the keys where the values are "true":

```
h = { :a => true, :b => false, :c =>true }
```

I've come up with this:

```
h.map {|k,v| k if v==true} - [nil]
```

Any alternatives?

Comment: map and select methods are aliases, so you can use one of them.

Comment: @sbagdat, to be precise, `map` and *`collect`* are aliases, not `select`. [`select`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/select) does different job and in case of Hash returns different type: it returns Hash, while map/collect return Array.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
h.select { |_, v| v }.keys
```

Will do the same, but in more readable way.

Comment: That's nice, thanks. However, to return an array you need to use to_a.

Comment: `keys` returns an `Array`. What else would it return?

Comment: It's a clever way but i am not sure it is a "more readable way".

Comment: Why not? Also this is more general case, as it will allow all "true" values, not only `true` (in Ruby, like in Scheme, anything except `nil` and `false` is true in condition, but `1 != true`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
s = {}
h.each do |k,v|
   s[k] = v if v==true
end
```